# How to create log file using pantheios?

Tags: c++, pantheios

My problem is similar what posted in How to log with pantheios to a file?  followed the steps but still not able to create log file using pantheios library. It is displaying in theconsole but not creating the log file.

```
pantheios::log_NOTICE("log-1");
pantheios_be_file_setFilePath("pantheiosLog.txt", PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_TRUNCATE,
    PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_TRUNCATE, PANTHEIOS_BEID_ALL);
pantheios::log_NOTICE("log-2");
```

And  i also don't know how to use pantheios_be_file_init and pantheios_be_file_logEntry functions.